# What is the smtp address of my Salesforce Org for SPF Purposes?

Tags: visualforce, lightning, community, email

If anyone can provide any advice, I am looking for the smtp server address for my salesforce org.  Where can this be found?

In summary: I am being asked to provide the smtp address to an individual.  This is so he can use it a SPF (send policy framework) for sending email.

Further summary: We are experiencing emails coming in as noreply@salesforce.com for the reply-to.  However, we want to avoid this - I have been informed I need to provide smtp information.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to provide more context. There isn't a single SMTP server for all of Salesforce.

Comment: @DavidReed Thanks for the feedback - I have edited the post.  Please let me know if this provides enough detail.  Will appreciate any advice.

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000354353&type=1&mode=1

Comment: Is it that you need to sign your outbound emails via DKIM so that your emails are sent by Salesforce but they come from 'yourdomain.com'?

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce uses a cloud of multiple SMTP servers.
Add the following entry to your SPF record:

```
include:_spf.salesforce.com
```